# grunt tasks hanging and not responding

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, patternlab.io

this is the first time I have this problem. I always use pretty much the same gruntfile configurations but at some point, my tasks are just hanging. more precisely they hang when triggered by `grunt-contrib-watch`. here's my config

```
watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['source/css/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass:dist','sass:styleguide_specific_styles', 'postcss', 'shell:patternlab_css'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                }
            },
        styleguide_specific_styles: {
            files: ['public/styleguide/css/styleguide-specific.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass:styleguide_specific_styles','sass:dist','shell:patternlab_css'],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        },
        }, //end of watch task
```

and my sass task

```
sass: {
            styleguide_specific_styles: {
                options: {
                    style: 'nested',
                    compass: 'true'
                },
                files: {
                    'public/styleguide/css/styleguide-specific.css': 'public/styleguide/css/styleguide-specific.scss'
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'nested',
                    compass: 'true'
                },
                files: {
                    'source/css/styleguide.css': 'source/css/styleguide.scss'
                }
            }
        }, //end of sass
```

When i edit and save an `.scss` file, i get stuck with this:

[image]

But if i stop grunt and just type `grunt sass` the compilation is successful.

I've tried removing compass, freshly reinstalling all dependencies copying the project elsewhere, updating grunt-contrib-sass , updating the sass gem, changing file permissions, updating nodejs but nothing seems to work. I'm on windows using this gruntfile config on a patternlab-php project.

The same configuration works on dozens of other projects, but not here.
And this is not the only task giving me this problem, all the others do the same.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution to this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @KaranThakkar i ditched patternlab :)